# I want to create a years_worked function in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, sql-function

I have a table with this create statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `dept_emp` (
 `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `dept_no` char(4) NOT NULL,
 `from_date` date NOT NULL,
 `to_date` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`dept_no`),
 KEY `emp_no` (`emp_no`),
 KEY `dept_no` (`dept_no`),
 CONSTRAINT `dept_emp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `dept_emp_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `departments` (`dept_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

here is some of the data on this table

| emp_no | dept_no | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | d005 | 1986-06-26 | 9999-01-01 |
| 10002 | d007 | 1996-08-03 | 9999-01-01 |
| 10008 | d005 | 1998-03-11 | 2000-07-31 |
| 10010 | d004 | 1996-11-24 | 2000-06-26 |
| 10010 | d006 | 2000-06-26 | 9999-01-01 |

then I used this query to get the years worked for one employee

```
SELECT
        DATEDIFF(
            MAX(
                IF(
                    to_date = "9999-01-01",
                    NOW(), to_date)
                ),
                MIN(from_date)
            ) / 365
            AS years_worked
         FROM dept_emp
    WHERE
        emp_no = 10010;
```

and it worked fine. this was the output

| years_worked |
| --- |
| 24.4603 |

then I tried turning it into a function like this, and it's not working

```
CREATE FUNCTION years_worked(emp_id INT) RETURNS double BEGIN
    DECLARE
        yw_double double;
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(
            MAX(
                IF(
                    to_date = "9999-01-01",
                    NOW(), to_date)
                ),
                MIN(from_date)
            ) / 365
        INTO yw_double FROM dept_emp
    WHERE
        emp_no = emp_id;
RETURN yw_double;
END;
```

I get this error message

Error
SQL query: Copy

CREATE FUNCTION years_worked(emp_id INT) RETURNS double BEGIN
DECLARE
yw_double double
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please provide a few rows of the working output, vs the not working output, so we can see what we are dealing with. (Maybe try to switch the order of `INTO` and `FROM`?)

Comment: what's the error showing up ?